# Installing NVidia Drivers - Blank Screen

Tags: graphic-drivers, command-line

I'm going through the steps to install my GTX 970 Driver onto my Elementary OS system but when I run the following command, I get a blank screen...

```
sudo sudo service lightdm stop
```

I believe I am supposed to get a terminal-type of screen, but am met with nothing at all. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can try to press CTRL+ALT+F1, then you have access to the terminal. By pressing CTRL+ALT+F7 you can switch back to the graphical surface.

Comment: By using CTRL+ALT+F1 I get a blank screen as well. Nothing is displayed. It lets me go back to the graphical interface still.

Comment: Where do you run this command? At the terminal, or at the graphical interface?

Comment: I ran it at the Terminal. I also attempted to use CTRL+ALT+F1 before using the command and I also get the same blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

Installing nvidia drivers manually is always a pain (ended up multiple times with a black screen after reboot)
I suggest installing the latest stable driver via the xorg edgers graphics drivers ppa:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Comment: The PPA you mention [doesn't contain any packages](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) whose name contain `nvidia`. So why shall we add it?

Comment: Apparently the drivers have been moved to another repsitory recently [see here](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: I think it might be more recommended to make them install `nvidia-current`. I tried 352 on older hardware (315M) and it didn't really turned out well.

Comment: The PPA you mention isn't stable. It's called "xorg edgers" for a reason. To install drivers just do `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Answer (score 1):

Type `software & updates` in Sling Shot. Open Software & Updates. Move to `Additional Drivers` pane. Check the if there are additional drivers listed there or not. If available then, choose the open that says: `(proprietary, tested)`

Check the visual demo [here](https://www.elementarynow.com/graphic-drivers-for-elementary-os/)