# Installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: graphics, nvidia

I have been having some issues installing Nvidia graphics drivers, I have tried many different things including things I've seen in other stack questions.

I tried:

- Installing manually using the .run from their website, following a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jansanchez/ce5b0ca1c5e538f4b266)
- Using the ppa's [found here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/installing-nvidia-drivers-blank-screen)

Things that I have ended up doing:

- Blacklisted nouveau in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`
- Ended up removing nouveau per suggestion found somewhere else to no change

Where I'm at:

- Black screen
- Occasionally stuck at a white 'e' (elementary icon)
- `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` final lines are giving

`[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration default
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat: Failed to create greeter session`

Any help would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset graphic drivers from command line](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/how-to-reset-graphic-drivers-from-command-line)

Comment: Very similar, however, I have done all of that and am currently running 352 as suggest for my card (GTX 750)

Comment: If you couldn't successfully install and use the NVidia drivers NEVER remove nouveau. I suggest reinstalling nouveau.

Comment: What would be the point of going back to nouveau? Giving up on the nvidia drivers? EDIT: my linux background is 100% server, never had a gui in my life, new to using the graphics drivers on linux

Comment: I'd install that noveau driver again and also synaptic. Then open synaptic and just check nvidia-352 and it'll do everything by itself

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the `nvidia-352` package and you need to disable `nouveau` (open source driver for Nvidia graphics) in `GRUB`.

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and log in by entering a username and password. **CAUTION: this will deactivate elementary OS's graphical interface, leaving you with a command line, so read this entire set of instructions first.**
2. Execute following commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
   sudo reboot
   ```
3. The computer will restart. When you get to the GRUB loader screen, select `elementary OS` and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key to edit that boot command.
4. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line.
5. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and boot.

Comment: I did these steps and now I have a blinking cursor when I boot. Is this graphics?

Comment: Press CTRL + Alt + F1 and log in by entering a username and password, then enter command nvidia-xconfig

Comment: Right, that's the first step. On the second step it requires a reboot. After reboot, I had only a blinking cursor and Ctrl alt f1, along with everything else, did nothing. It's like the operating system, Grub and everything else was gone. I just installed Windows at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the additional hardware tool that ships by default in Ubuntu, and this will configure your system with the latest versions of the drivers you need at the click of a button.

See: [Loki, additional hardware](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7587/loki-additional-hardware)

Answer (score 0):

In Elementary OS 4.1, there is a AppCenter app.

In the AppCenter, there is a "**Nvidia X Server Settings**" app. Install that and reboot.

After rebooting, there will be a **driver update in the AppCenter for "nvidia-375"**.  At time of writing, nvidia-375 is the latest long term driver.  Install nvidia-375 and reboot.  The computer will be using the proprietary Nvidia driver now.

Prior to this, you could see that the nouveau driver was being used via terminal: `lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'` which shows `driver=nouveau latency=0`. After updating, it will show `driver=nvidia latency=0`

Comment: rebooting was the key for me! thanks