# Loki, additional hardware

Tags: settings, release-loki, hardware, drivers

How do I access the additional hardware/drivers menu in Loki?
Am I missing something or was this GUI option removed?

Comment: Anyone know why this menu was removed, or where i can access it now??

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
```

after install -> software-properties-gtk

Info retrieved from -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/441415/what-has-jockey-been-replaced-with-in-14-04/441416

Tested and implemented successful here - sure someone with more Linux experience may have an even better suggestion perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. Awesome.  Exactly what i was looking for. Know why it isnt included with the base install in loki?

Comment: @ZacharySutton I read elsewhere that it was done to prevent people from adding PPAs. I would suggest reporting a bug about this.