# How to fix screen tearing with Nvidia GTX 970M Elementary OS?

Tags: display, nvidia

I've tried so many things to stop the screen tearing and nothing has worked. I have given compton ago, nvidia full pipe line setting, nvidia full power setting and nothing works.

I really like elementary os but the screen tearing is a big issue for me. Is there any way which works in order to stop screen tearing?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4267/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-my-nvidia-gtx-970

Answer (score 1):

Take this with a grain of salt, as I am a fresh Linux user. I have an AMD card and had the same issue. Everything was blurry in games and "out of sync" as I will describe it. I found somewhere somebody suggesting running these commands.

- `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:eek:ibaf/graphics-drivers`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

I actually did this and then later played Torchlight II. Whatever this did made a big difference as things were way more smooth and less blurry/out of sync. Thus, I believe this task may help you. I just don't know exactly it does.

Interestingly, I just tried to run it again as a test and now I get

- `ERROR: '~eek' user or team does not exist.`

So maybe just running

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

is what did the trick for me.

Hopefully someone with more experience will have some drivers for you.